# Acceptance region for a exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

The half-life of 100 electronic components is 260 hours. Suppose that the life of the components is like an exponential of $\lambda$. For $\alpha = 0.05$ I want to do the next test ($\mu$ is the half-life)
$H_0 : \mu = 300$ and $H_1 : \mu < 300$.

Then
$$
\overline{X} = \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_{100}}{100} \sim exp(\lambda).
$$
The relationship between $\lambda$ and $\mu$ is $\mu = 1/\lambda$ because $E[\overline{X}] = 1/\lambda$. $H_0$ is true if $|\overline{X}| \leq k$. Then I am going to calculate this $k$.
$$
\alpha = 0.05 = P(|\overline{X}| > k | \mu = 300) = P(\overline{X}< k_1|\lambda = 1/300) + P(\overline{X}>k_2|\lambda = 1/300).
$$
If
$$
P(\overline{X}<k_1) = 0.025 
$$
then $k_1 = 7.6$ and with the same argument $k_2 = 1106,66$. I think that this acceptance region is so large and I am not sure that it's correct. And there is another question in this exercises because it says that if $\mu = 250$ really then what is the probability that this test detect this fact.

Comment: What's the "medium life"?

Comment: half-life, sorry

Comment: The mean of exponentially distributed variables has [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution), not exponential distribution.

Comment: so, how can I do this test?

Comment: Are you not going to correct the question?

Comment: yes, but $X_1 + \cdots + X_{100} \sim Er(100,\lambda)$ but $\overline{X}?

Comment: $\overline X\sim\operatorname{Er}(100,100\lambda)$. You can scale the values of the Erlang distribution like you can scale the values of the exponential distribution, by scaling the rate parameter. You can see this from the fact that in both distributions $x$ only appears in the combination $\lambda x$ in the cumulative distribution function.